# How do I get Tree Shaking to work in Vuetify when using JSX?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, jsx

I am currently building a project with Nuxt(2.14.8). I am using @nuxtjs/vuetify(1.11.2) as my UI Library. I am building all of my components using JSX. If any of you are wondering why I am using JSX, I have to use it since it was a team decision. Majority of the team was using React prior to this project so that was the compromise for using Vue.

In my nuxt.config.js file I have the vuetify option treeShake set to true. When I `npm run dev` or `npm run build` I find that my app does not render correctly. There is no styling what so ever being applied from vuetify.

When I change my vuetify option treeShake to false I can then see all of vuetify's styling. During the development stage this is fine. When I build this for production I would like the tree shaking version to work to minimize my build size.

I found that a similar question has already been asked: https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module/issues/377

Unfortunately the only solution in the issue above is to turn off tree shaking which means I lose the ability to minimize my bundle size.

Has anyone out there experienced this and found a solution yet? Please comment below if I need to supply more information.